How to apply a different delay on different number of requests in laravel Rate Limit?
I am writing a rate limits middleware in which i have to do a folowing functionality
1:Sending first is instant the second request will ask you to wait 30 seconds, third will ask to wait 60 seconds, 4th will ask to wait 120 seconds (This is by number)
2:If the ip send 10 requests in a minute block it for 3 hours. I am stuck here it is not getting the count of attempts I am unable to add a custom delay functionality can you please tell me where I am getting wrong and what to do? I am applying these for the first time
Code:
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
$limiter = app(RateLimiter::class);
$key = sha1($request->ip());
$maxAttempts = 4;
$hitCount = $limiter->attempts($key);
if ($hitCount == 2)
{
$decayMinutes = 30;
}
elseif ($hitCount == 3)
{
$decayMinutes = 60;
}
elseif ($hitCount == 4)
{
$decayMinutes = 120;
}
else
{
$decayMinutes = 10;
}
if ($limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts))
{
$retryAfter = $limiter->availableIn($key);
return new Response('Rate limit exceeded. Please wait ' . $retryAfter . ' seconds before making another request.', 429);
}
$limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes);
$response = $next($request);
return $response;
}

Now this code is continuously sending request without any wait.
I have tried this without any count hit with maximum attempts 1 it was working fine but now i am trying to give the different delay for different number of requests it is not working as expected.

Please try with this....
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $limiter = app(RateLimiter::class);
  $key = sha1($request->ip());
  $maxAttempts = 4;
  $decayMinutes = 10; // Default decay time

  $hitCount = $limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes); // Hit the limiter  first

if ($hitCount > $maxAttempts) {
    $retryAfter = $limiter->availableIn($key);
    return new Response('Rate limit exceeded. Please wait ' . $retryAfter . ' seconds before making another request.', 429);
}

  if ($hitCount == 2) {
    $decayMinutes = 30;
  } elseif ($hitCount == 3) {
    $decayMinutes = 60;
  } elseif ($hitCount == 4) {
    $decayMinutes = 120;
  }

  $response = $next($request);
  return $response;
}


it is making 4 request in a row then returning the wait time : Rate limit exceeded. Please wait 4 seconds before making another request.

I have updated the code, please try again.

giving the delay when it is reaching to maxAttempts not giving custom releases it is working on maxattempts i think we may not getting the right number of attempts??
